# Check for duplicate entry in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, table

I have created a table **abc_bar/baz** [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104046/unable-to-save-multi-selected-values-to-db-from-magento-admin-form-and-render-it/104055?noredirect=1#comment141501_104055), I want that it's filed **name** should be unique, is there an easy way in magento to check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller `saveAction` method you can do the following:

```
// Retrieve the possible entities with same name
$existingEntities = Mage::getResourceModel('abc_bar/baz_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name',$postData['name']);
if ($existingEntities->getSize())
{
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Sorry the entity name must be unique and it seems like another entity has the same name'));
        $this->_redirectReferer();
}
// Only add the data if the test pass
$model->setData($postData)
```